# Trying to prove slope of a point on the exponential function $2^x$ without derivatives.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponential-function

Slope of a point on the exponential function $2^x$

So I know about derivatives, and that the derivative of $2^x$ is ln($2$) * $2^x$, so the slope is
ln($2$) * $2^x$ for a given 'x'.

However, I'm tasked to show this without derivatives. Here is what I have so far: $2^x$ = $e^{ln(2^x)}$ = $e^{x*ln(2)}$. How should I continue from here?

Comment: The slope at a point *is* the derivative. Asking "what is the slope without derivatives" is nonsense. It's like asking someone to translate "Hello, how are you?" to French, but without using foreign languages.

Comment: Now, maybe what you're looking for is to compute the slope (the derivative of $2^x$) without using the *formula* you have learned for derivatives of exponentials, in which case maybe something can be done...

Comment: I see what you mean. But my teacher unfortunately says we're not allowed to use derivative rules yet. I should've been clearer. I just don't have a way to show that e^{x * ln(2) proves the derivative of 2^x at x is ln(2) * 2^x

Comment: Yes you're right, I'm trying to compute the slope without the formula

Answer (score 1):

Derivative of a function f(x) at x can be written as

$$ f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} {{f(x+h) - f(x)} \over h }$$ .
Here , $f(x) = a^x $, therefore ,

Derivative =$$ f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} {{a^{x+h} - a^x } \over h } = \lim_{h \to 0} {{a^x(a^h -1)} \over h }$$ ...(1)

Now we know that $\lim_{h \to 0} {{a^h - 1} \over h} =  \ln{a} $

Therefore , (1) becomes ,
$$f'(x) = a^x{ \ln a}$$

Answer (score -1):

Use the definition of derivative:

$f^\prime(x) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$,

$f^\prime(x) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{2^{(x+\Delta x)}-2^x}{\Delta x}=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{2^x(2^{\Delta x}-1)}{\Delta x}$

$f^\prime(x) = 2^x\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{2^{\Delta x}-1}{\Delta x}$,

Now, you can use your idea of writing $2^{\Delta x} = e^{\Delta x\ln 2}$. From the Taylor series,

$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$, hence

$e^{\Delta x\ln 2} = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{\Delta x^n\ln^n 2}{n!}= 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\Delta x^n\ln^n 2}{n!}$, hence

$e^{\Delta x\ln 2}-1 = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\Delta x^n\ln^n 2}{n!}$, hence

$\frac{e^{\Delta x\ln 2}-1}{\Delta x} = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\Delta x^{n-1}\ln^n 2}{n!} = \ln 2 + \frac{\Delta x \ln^2 2}{2!} + \frac{\Delta x^2 \ln^3 2}{3!} + \dots$, hence

$f^\prime(x) = 2^x\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\ln 2 + \frac{\Delta x \ln^2 2}{2!} + \frac{\Delta x^2 \ln^3 2}{3!} + \dots$, yielding

$f^\prime(x) = 2^x \ln 2$